# Why does my keras model get good accuracy but bad predictions?

Tags: python, numpy, model, keras, prediction

So, I am trying to make a model which can predict doodles. I am using google's quick draw data :https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/quickdraw_dataset/full/numpy_bitmap which are images rendered into 28x28 greyscale bitmap numpy array. I only chose 10 classes and took 60,000 photos to train/evaluate. I get a test accuracy of 91% . When I try to make predictions with data from test data, it works. But when i make a drawing in paint and convert it into 28x28, it doesn't make good predictions. What sort of data do I need to have? What kind of preprocessing does the image need?

This is how i preprocessed the data from google's npy file

```
def load_set(name,path,resultx,resulty,label):
    loaded_set = np.load(path+name+".npy")
    loaded_set = loaded_set.reshape(loaded_set.shape[0],1,28,28)
   # print(name,loaded_set.shape)
    loaded_set = loaded_set[0:6000,0:6000,0:6000,0:6000]
    resultx = np.append(resultx,loaded_set,axis=0)
    resulty = createLabelArray(label,loaded_set.shape[0],resulty)
    print("loaded "+name)
    return resultx,resulty

def createLabelArray(label,size,result):
    for i in range(0,size):
        result = np.append(result,[[label]],axis=0)
    return result
```

where label is the label i want for that category.
I shuffle them afterwards and everything.
And this is how I am trying to process new images(drawings by me):

```
print("[INFO] loading and preprocessing image...")
image = image_utils.load_img(os.path.join(path, name), grayscale=True,target_size=(28, 28))
image = image_utils.img_to_array(image)
print(image.shape)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
print(image.shape)
image = image.astype('float32')
image /= 255
return image
```

Please help, I've been stuck on this for a while now. Thank you

Comment: I don't know how big is your dataset and how many training examples you have. But assuming that you have enough training/testing examples to learn a very generalizable model, if you want to generalize a learned model to images drawn by you, you would have to either 1) add few of your drawings to your validation set or 2) preprocess your drawings with the same preprocessing done in the dataset.

Comment: What do you mean by "i make a drawing in paint"? Is it from one of the 10 classes you trained on, or any other? And how close it matches the train data?

Comment: My drawing is from one of the categories. I think the problem is the preprocessing. I am not really sure of the preprocessing done in the dataset. I have the .npy files from google. The curious thing is, If i keep some of the data and not put it in the network then try and predict on those data which are unseen for my network, it predicts correctly. So, I think the problem is how to preprocess an image which i can draw so that it matches the preprocessing of my data

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a typical case of overfitting.

Please try 10-fold cross-validation to get accuracy of model.
Further use regularization and dropout in keras to prevent overfitting.

Comment: I don't think it is the case of overfitting. I think I do not preprocess the new images of doodles which i make properly. The model predicts well if i give it unseen data from the google data. And it gets 91% accuracy on test data.